# Dismissing UIImagePickerController broke parent viewController's frame size - iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

When I dismissing UIImagePickerController (presented modally) with media type kUTTypeMovie - on iOS 8 it broke parent viewController's frame size by 20px (status bar height). On iOS 7 all works fine.

Presenting picker code:

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
picker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hiding picker code:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^
    {
    }];
}
```

Project uses storyboard, I'm using xCode 6.1

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout/constraints?   Are you using UINavigationBar?  If updating the frame programmatically, did you set translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints to false for the relevant views?  I don't have a good clear answer, but these are the kinds of things I might investigate if I had that issue (as well as come to Stack Overflow for help :) )  Don't forget to up-vote any answers below that help, and be sure to accept the answer that actually solves your problem after. That's how people earn reputation here, and you will too as you participate.

Comment: @1s and 0s thanks for answer :-) Yes, I'm using UINavigationBar there, but I'm not updating my viewcontroller's frame programmatically. It's just get wrong size after dissmissing picker, and there is no problem when I show this picker with mediaTypes set to kUTTypeImage

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide status bar in view will appear & your ViewDidLoad of the class in which you are calling imagepicker using below code.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];

});
```

also you need set status bar to show in ViewDidAppear :

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];

});
```